# File manager time to run --- why are some very slow?

Tags: nautilus, file-manager, nemo, thunar, pcmanfm

Some file managers open very slow on kubuntu, bullseye 11.
I had a problem on UDisks2VolumeMonitor, so fixing this, halved the time needed to run.
(ps. UDisks2VolumeMonitor --> problem on mraid2 not fixed)

fixed by applying some of these:

```
sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk2-module
chmod +x /usr/libexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor 
sudo apt install --reinstall glib2 -y
sudo apt install --reinstall gsettings-desktop-schemas
fixing XDG_DATA_DIRS paths

references: 
Do you have overlay scrollbars activated? If yes, take a look at this bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-settings/+bug/1239014
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gvfs/-/issues/541
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=950174
```

So i measured the time these file managers need to run on my system:
Dolphin and Krusader less than 10sec.. other more then 30sec.

Note: I have 8 usb HDD on self-powered usb hub mounted.

So i would like to trace why eg. Nautilus takes 1 while minute to run!!! How i can do this?

Do you recommend any other file manager that can be faster (NOT Terminal based)?

```
nemo 
Current gtk theme is not known to have nemo support (Adwaita), adding some... 
real    0m34.582s
user    0m0.755s
sys     0m0.036s

after some changes / updates - no error on UDisks2VolumeMonitor
Current gtk theme is not known to have nemo support (Adwaita), adding some... 
real    0m28.351s
user    0m0.538s
sys 0m0.048s


Nautilus
error StartServiceByName for rg.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor:
real    1m20.784s
user    0m0.878s
sys 0m0.072s

after some changes / updates - no error on UDisks2VolumeMonitor
real    0m55.335s
user    0m0.642s
sys 0m0.080s


thunar 
error StartServiceByName for rg.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor:
real    0m54.789s
user    0m0.465s
sys 0m0.076s

thunar 
after some changes / updates - no error on UDisks2VolumeMonitor
real    0m29.717s
user    0m0.523s
sys 0m0.125s



pcmanfm
WARNING **: 10:19:01.112: XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR is set to invalid path, ignoring it
error StartServiceByName for rg.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor:
real    0m52.694s
user    0m0.250s
sys 0m0.032s

after some changes / updates - no error on UDisks2VolumeMonitor
WARNING **: 10:19:01.112: XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR is set to invalid path, ignoring it
real    0m27.530s
user    0m0.410s
sys 0m0.094s


dolphin
QApplication: invalid style override 'GTK+' passed, ignoring it.
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 5 (BadAtom), sequence: 628, resource id: 0, major code: 20 (GetProperty), minor code: 0
real    0m7.418s
user    0m0.833s
sys 0m0.091s

QApplication: invalid style override 'GTK+' passed, ignoring it.
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 5 (BadAtom), sequence: 628, resource id: 0, major code: 20 (GetProperty), minor code: 0
real    0m2.385s
user    0m0.708s
sys 0m0.087s


krusader 
NOT TESTED WITH UDisks2VolumeMonitor error
warning default unknown@0 # QApplication: invalid style override 'GTK+' passed, ignoring it
real    0m2.268s
user    0m0.684s
sys 0m0.207s
```

Comment: Does performance improve if you disconnect that USB hub?

Comment: I am not intented to try this. Why dolpin and krusader open quicker than others?

Comment: Tested with firefox, removing nautilus (and then) nemo, resulted right click open menu save as in firefox 10 times faster than before (1-2s vs 30s).